# Software to limit screen area available for programs running in full screen mode

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, utility

I have rather specific request that may even look absurd. I believe it is not, though. I'd like Windows 10 taskbar to be always visible even if some program goes full screen (or to be able to see windows for two programs each of which ist running in full screen mode side-by-side). In other words I am looking for a software that could control screen area available for other programs tricking them into believing this area is the whole screen.

I know about one such program called Fanix Fullscreen. Unfortunately, it looks like it has been abandoned long time ago and is obsolete by today's standards (I can confirm it does not work for many modern pieces of software).

Any suggestions are welcome!